# Rails Devise password edit not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, passwords

I have the following link in a menu:

```
<li><%= link_to "Change your password", edit_user_registration_path %>
```

This is in my route:

```
devise_for :users
```

When the link gets clicked, I get the following routing error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"devise/admin"}
```

I do not understand what I am doing wrong.

Here are the devise routes :

```
        new_user_session GET    /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#new
        user_session POST   /users/sign_in(.:format)          devise/sessions#create
destroy_user_session GET    /users/sign_out(.:format)         devise/sessions#destroy
       user_password POST   /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#create
   new_user_password GET    /users/password/new(.:format)     devise/passwords#new
  edit_user_password GET    /users/password/edit(.:format)    devise/passwords#edit
                     PUT    /users/password(.:format)         devise/passwords#update
 cancel_user_registration GET    /users/cancel(.:format)    devise/registrations#cancel
   user_registration POST   /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#create
new_user_registration GET    /users/sign_up(.:format)         devise/registrations#new
edit_user_registration GET    /users/edit(.:format)           devise/registrations#edit
                     PUT    /users(.:format)
                     PUT    /users(.:format)               devise/registrations#update
                     DELETE /users(.:format)            devise/registrations#destroy
```

Comment: The link/route is looking for `devise/admin` but you've setup your routes as `devise_for :users`.

Comment: The funny part is that I have only a user model.
I use simple_roles and cancan. All users are admin but I never changed the devise routes...
Strange...

Comment: Can you paste your routes? bundle exec rake routes | grep devise

Comment: I put the devise routes in my post.

Answer (score 1):

I think the path for the Change password link is `edit_password_url` if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing more of your code, the best solution I can offer is just rip out devise and put it back in. Just run the rails d command reversing the generate command that created devise and start over.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell rails who you are editing password for

the correct way would be like this

```
<li><%= link_to "Change your password", edit_user_registration_path(current_user) %>
```

current_user is a helper provided by devise. hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

If you have a devise model **User**, you can use this path to route to the change password page:

```
edit_user_registration_path
```

And then you can use this in your view like this:

```
<%= link_to 'Change Password', edit_user_registration_path %>
```